# Remove all Instance on stage as3

Tags: actionscript-3

Im having trouble on removing instances on the stage.

The error I keep getting after I click the button 2 times is

"The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller"

Can somebody help me with this?

```
package src
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Main extends MovieClip
{   
    var positionY:Number = 80;
    var positionX:Number = 0;
    var motion:MovieClip;
    var fCombo:Array = new Array();
    var n:Number;

public function Main()
{
    generate.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, loop); 
    generate.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, remove); 
    n = Number(inputText.text);
}
function loop(me:MouseEvent):void
{
    var combo:Array = [Punch, Kick, Knee, Elbow];
    n = Number(inputText.text);
    for(var i:Number = 0;i < n;i++ )
        {
        motion = new combo[randomNumber(4)]();  
        fCombo.push(motion);
        motion.y = positionY;
        motion.x = positionX;
        positionX += 100;
        addChild(motion);
            if (i == 4 || i == 9 || i == 14)
                {
                    positionY += 40;
                    positionX = 0;
                }
        }
}
function remove(me:MouseEvent):void
{
    for (var j:Number = 0; j < n; j++ )
    {
        removeChild(fCombo[j]);//error
    }
    positionY = 80;
    positionX = 0;
}

function randomNumber(max:Number):Number
    {
    return(Math.floor(Math.random() * max ));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where does the `j` in `removeChild(fCombo[j]);//error` come from? It doesn't seem to be initialized.

Comment: And what exactly are you trying to do? Remove last added combo from the display? Remove currently clicked combo from the display?

Comment: I'm trying to remove every instance in the stage

Comment: Okay, I see j, but I'dont see `k` initialization now. Does `k` refer to the `fCombo.length`?

Comment: Can't see any errors here. Try to check if combo really is a child of the stage: `if (this.contains(fCombo[j])) removeChild(fCombo[j])`.

Comment: The error is gone,but after the 2nd time you click the button it doesn't remove the instance.Causing it to be overlaped by the next intances and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the new objects you create to the array, and then using that to remove them. But you're forgetting to either create a new list or remove the objects from the old list. So, when time comes to loop over the list you're trying to remove objects that have already been removed.

You can fix this in several ways, one is to remove objects from the stage AND array in your loop:

```
function remove(me:MouseEvent):void
{
    while(fCombo.length)
    {
        removeChild(fCombo.pop());
    }
    positionY = 80;
    positionX = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

targetDisplayObject.parent.removeChild( targetDisplayObject ); does the trick assuming the parent is not null.